# Service workers and cross-origin file downloads

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have a basic service worker that for now just logs fetches.

```js
self.addEventListener('install', (e) => {
  self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (e) => {
  return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Once registered, it handles any Fetch API requests from the current origin *or* cross-origin.

```js
// This works, and is logged by the Service Worker
await fetch('/some/local/path/woot.txt');

// This also works, and is logged by the Service Worker
await fetch('https://cross-origin.example.com/woot.txt');
```

I can even programmatically a download that is logged by my Service Worker.

```js
location.href = '/test.bin';
```

However, I **cannot** get the Service Worker to intercept requests for a cross-origin download.

```js
// The Service Worker never sees this request
location.href = 'https://cross-origin.example.com/test.bin';
```

My questions:

- Why is this the case?  Is this specified in the [W3C standard](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/), or is this an implementation quirk?
- Is there a good way to solve this problem?  I'm currently solving it by requesting a path like `/download/https://cross-origin.example.com/test.bin`, which is intercepted by the Service Worker, however this isn't a good solution as I have no real way of knowing if the Service Worker is actively running.

---

**Update:**  I found this:  https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1653

The relevant comment:

> …(Downloads are navigations.) Navigation requests match their URL against registration scope in order to find a service worker to handle a fetch event. So in this case only a service worker owned by dl.boxcloud.com could intercept the navigation request.

So, that explains the behavior I'm seeing.  Now, to find the cleanest way around the issue.